# video.js currentTime() incorrect until timeupdate event fires

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I've noticed a small inconsistency that I'm hoping to verify as either a quirk of HTML5, or something specific to [Video.js](http://videojs.com).

It seems that if you call Video.js' `currentTime()` function whilst providing a new time, any further calls to `currentTime()` (to get the current time) will not return the correct time (it will return the previous time), until the `timeupdate` event fires. After the `timeupdate` event, `currentTime()` will return the correct time.

For example, assuming the video hasn't started playing yet, but Video.js has loaded, along with all the video meta etc:

```
videoPlayer.addEvent('timeupdate', function() {
    console.log('Event callback: ' + player.currentTime); 
});
console.log('Original time: ' + player.currentTime);  
player.currentTime(100);          
console.log('New time: ' + player.currentTime);
```

The output I was expecting would look like:

```
Original time: 0
New time: 100
Event callback: 100
```

However what I've receiving is:

```
Original time: 0
New time: 0
Event callback: 100
```

Any insight would be fantastic!

**Edit:** I can reproduce this in Chrome and Safari on OSX, but not Firefox on OSX (all using HTML5). I can also reproduce this on IE8 using the Flash player and IE9 using the HTML5 player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen similar behaviour on several other html5/flash players.

I've always been under the assumption that even after seeking via `currentTime(100);`, the playhead will not be updated until the next `timeupdate` event.

Comment: This seems to be the case through my experimentation. Cheers!